# How to make form inline labels not inline?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I used a form inline with [React Bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-inline) because I wanted all of my fields to be on one line. What I didn't realize is that I didn't want my labels to also be on the same line like:

[image]

I would like my text fields to display that way, but I want my labels to be on top of the text fields... like:

[image]

Is there any way I can do that? I tried `<ControlLabel></ControlLabel>`, but of course that just does an inline label.

This is my a snippet of my code:

```
<Form inline className="margin-bottom-5">\
        <ControlLabel>Company</ControlLabel> <!-- Doesn't work -->
        <FormControl
          type='text'
          placeholder='Company'

        />
        {' '}
        <ControlLabel>Title</ControlLabel> <!-- Doesn't work -->
        <FormControl
          type='text'
          placeholder='Title'
        />
        {' '}
        <ControlLabel>Start Month</ControlLabel> <!-- Doesn't work -->
        <FormGroup>
          <Select
              className="dropDownWidth"
              placeholder='Start Month'
              options={select_options['Months']}
        {' '}
       </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Is there any way else to make this happen? I'm new to CSS so just not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreaciated, thanks!!

Comment: `display: block`?

Comment: put each control in a div.  Then put a <br /> after each label.   add float:left and a width

Comment: do you have a sample of the generated html? that would help us figure out the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with those who have commented, add a `display: block;` to your labels.  But I would add another thing, I would put each group of form and label in a div together, and float them left, so that they all stack up.  This way, you keep each form/label group next to each other on the same line.

```
<Form inline className="margin-bottom-5">
<div class = "some-other-class">
    <label class ="some-class"> Company </label> 
    <FormControl
      type='text'
      placeholder='Company'

    />
</div>
    {' '}
<div class = "some-other-class">
    <label>Title</label> 
    <FormControl
      type='text'
      placeholder='Title'
    />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.some-class{
display: block;
}

.some-other-class{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, and made my labels on one line! I'll keep this in the mind for the future :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the object a [block element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

```
form label {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the first, but unfortunately, I still need the text fields and selects to display on the same row, and all of the labels to display on the same row. With this, the inputs get stacked because each label is on a new line